# MQ Explorer vs MQ Explorer Eclipse Plugin - Connection Issues

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mq

Setting up MQ Connection to a remote queue manager via the MQ Explorer downloaded and installed on Windows machine works like a charm.

The opposite is the case when installing the MQ Explorer Plugin on my M1 MacOs (Ventura 13.2) system an setting up the same Connection I do get following Message when trying to connect

```
An unexpected error (2393) has occurred. (AMQ4999)
  An unexpected error (2393) has occurred. (AMQ4999)
  Severity: 10 (Warning)
  Explanation: An unlisted error has occurred in the system while retrieving PCF data.
  Response: Try the operation again. If the error persists, examine the problem determination information to see if any details have been recorded.
```

Any ideas what could be different when working with the plugin? Or what I should think of?

Comment: 2393 is MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR - perhaps you could enhance the details of your question with your various SSL/TLS settings?

Comment: Which distribution and version of java are you using? Run `java -version`

Comment: openjdk64-11.0.11